# how can I pass the output of a command to a function in bash

Tags: bash, function

I'm facing an issue when trying to create a function, I have a code to detect a bluetooth dongle connected to a usb, which is the first part of the code, and it works fine, if the usb is indeed plugged in, then it checks its stats (UP or DOWN) and storages it in the ***bt_stat*** variable which is printer after all, so far everything works fine

```
#!/bin/bash
clear    
echo "Looking for bluetooth USB"
bt_id=`lsusb|grep ASUS|cut -c24-32`
bt_stat="0"
    if [[ -z "$bt_id" ]]; then
        echo "not found"
        exit 1 
    else
        bt_stat=`hciconfig|head -3|tail -1|grep "UP\|DOWN"`
        echo "USB BT found"
    fi
echo $bt_stat
```

**OUTPUT:**

**USB BT found**

**UP RUNNING**

the problem starts when I try to pass that variable to a function

```
function disp
{
    eval st1="$1"
    echo "Status: ${st1}"
}
```

The function it self works as well, I have pass a fixed variable and the output, as expected is "Status: TEST"

```
var="TEST"
disp "\${var}"
```

but the moment I place the function at the beginning of the code, even if I don't use it, then the assignation of the command to the variable **bt_stat** is not even made, what can be causing this? do I have to take something in consideration when making a function in a program that is assigning the output of a command to a variable?

below is how the code looks with the function, I'm sorry for the long question, but I wanted it to be clear

```
#!/bin/bash
function disp
{
    eval st1="$1"
    echo "Status: ${st1}"
}
clear    
echo "Looking for bluetooth USB"
bt_id=`lsusb|grep ASUS|cut -c24-32`
bt_stat="0"
    if [[ -z "$bt_id" ]]; then
        echo "not found"
        exit 1 
    else
        bt_stat=`hciconfig|head -3|tail -1|grep "UP\|DOWN"`
        echo "USB BT found"
    fi
echo $bt_stat
```

**OUTPUT:**

**USB BT found**

an additional line shows if I call with **disp "\${bt_stat}"** the function, but the assignation is still not taking place

**Status:**

Comment: Your question is quite long and difficult to follow, if you try to reduce to only the parts that are needed + format it, then you will likely get more responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could do it easier:

```
#!/bin/bash
function disp
{
    local st1="$1"
    echo "Status: ${st1}"
}

clear

echo "Looking for bluetooth USB"
bt_id=`lsusb|grep ASUS|cut -c24-32`
bt_stat=""
if [[ -z "$bt_id" ]]; then
    echo "not found"
    exit 1
else
    bt_stat=`hciconfig|head -3|tail -1|grep "UP\|DOWN"`
    echo "USB BT found"
fi

disp "$bt_stat"
```